# Баг с анимацией в Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome

В Firefox этот код работает отлично, но в Chrome всё содержимое этого раздела не отображается после того, как был закрыт последний активный элемент. Пятый пункт, если идти по всем пунктам по порядку.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mj68Lo4/2/).

JS:

```
var markets = {
    radius: 250, // in px

    init: function () {
        $('.markets-item a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var market = $(this).parent('.markets-item');

            if (market.hasClass('active')) {
                markets.showMarkets(market);
                return false;
            }

            markets.showItem(market);

            return false;
        });

        $('#markets-wrap').css('min-height', $('#markets-wrap').height() + 'px');
    },

    showItem: function (market) {
        $('.markets-item').removeClass('active fadeIn').removeAttr('style');

        market.addClass('active');

        var notActivedItems = $('.markets-item:not(.active)');

        notActivedItems.addClass('fadeOut');

        $('.markets-item:not(.active):last').one(animatedend, function () {
            var offset = market.position();

            market.data('top', offset.top)
                .data('left', offset.left)
                .css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: offset.top + 'px',
                left: offset.left + 'px'
            })
                .animate({
                top: 0,
                left: 7
            }, 0, function () {
                notActivedItems.hide().removeClass('fadeOut');
                markets.showSubmarkets(market);

                var img = market.children('a').children('img');

                market.data('src', img.attr('src'));
                img.attr('src', 'images/icons/back.png');
            });
        });
    },

    showMarkets: function (market) {
        market.children('a').children('img').attr('src', market.data('src'));

        var submarkets = $('.submarket:visible');

        if (0 === submarkets.length) {
            markets._show(market);
            return;
        }

        submarkets.addClass('fadeOut');

        $('.submarket:visible:last').one(animatedend, function () {
            submarkets.removeClass('fadeOut').hide();
            markets._show(market);
        });
    },

    _show: function (market) {
        var notActivedItems = $('.markets-item:not(.active)');

        market.animate({
            top: market.data('top') + 'px',
            left: market.data('left') + 'px'
        }, 0, function () {
            market.removeAttr('style').removeClass('active');


            notActivedItems.show().addClass('fadeIn').one(animatedend, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('fadeIn');
            });
        });
    },

    showSubmarkets: function (market) {
        var items = market.children('.submarket');

        if (0 === items.length) return;

        var delta = Math.PI / 3 / items.length;
        var x = 0,
            y = 0,
            angle = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items.eq(i).css({
                left: markets.radius * Math.cos(angle) + 'px',
                top: markets.radius * Math.sin(angle) + 'px',
                display: 'list-item'
            })
                .addClass('animated fadeIn')
                .one(animatedend, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('fadeIn');
            });
            angle += delta;
        }
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<section id="markets">
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="text-center">KEY SECTORS</h3>
        <div class="row text-center" id="markets-wrap">
            <ul class="markets-container">
                <li class="markets-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/icons/food.png" class="img-responsive"><br>
                        Food and Drink
                    </a>                    
                    <div class="submarket">Hot and Cold food containers/boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Hot and Cold drink cups</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Bags (paper, non-woven, fabric)</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Postal boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Printed ribbon</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Sticky labels</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Grease proof paper</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Custom retail packaging</div>
                </li>
                <li class="markets-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/icons/fashion.png" class="img-responsive"><br>
                        Fashion and Jewellery
                    </a>                    
                    <div class="submarket">Retail boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Luxury jewellery boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Exclusive souvenir boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Shopping bags</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Garment bags</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Printed ribbon</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Tissue paper</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Fabric pouches</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Hat boxes</div>
                </li>
                <li class="markets-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/icons/bakery.png" class="img-responsive"><br>
                        Bakery and Confectionery
                    </a>                    
                    <div class="submarket">Cake boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Specialist cake bags </div>
                    <div class="submarket">Bakery goods boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Printed ribbon</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Cake  trays</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Tin packaging</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Luxury confectionery boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Bags</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Sticky labels</div>
                </li>
                <li class="markets-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/icons/cosmetics.png" class="img-responsive"><br>
                        Cosmetics
                    </a>
                    <div class="submarket">Glassware</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Custom retail packaging</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Luxury boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Bags</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Specialist perfume labels</div>
                </li>
                <li class="markets-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/icons/goods.png" class="img-responsive"><br>
                        Place for your sector
                    </a>
                    <div class="submarket">As trendsetters and true connoisseurs of packaging  we are always excited to explore new 
                    grounds across the industry. If your sector or  a product you are looking for, is not listed, please do get in touch. </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>          
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Пройтись отладчиком?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.